# Java SE or Java ME on Raspberry Pi? Is Java ME on Pi stil useful?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, java-me

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 and searched for tutorials about *Java on Raspberry*. Most tutorials recommended to use the micro version of Java, Java ME. But I was wondering if it still has an advantage over using Java SE. I just wrote my programs in Java SE on my laptop and then transferred the executable jar to the Pi and that works fine, too. 
And even if you don't have a laptop or only want to use the Pi, the Raspberry Pi 4 has enough storage and runs fast enough, so that you can install Java SE on the Pi and just code directly there? And with Pi4J you can also access the GPIOs from Java SE.

So is there nowadays still an advantage of using Java ME for programs on the Pi that I missed?